# How to concatenate model field values in pre_save Django

Tags: django, django-models

I don't know how to ask this question so please bear with me.

Here is my problem:

I have two models `Foo` and `Bar`. Following is it's `models.py`,

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)


class Bar(models.Model):
    foo_rel = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now, `foo_code` is let say `123456` then I when I am creating new `Bar` instance I want `bar_code` to be `{{foo_code}}-{{id of Bar}}`, i.e. `123456-01`.

I am not able get my way around. I thought of using `pre_save`/`post_save` but can't think of logic. Please help!

EDIT: added FK to `Foo`

Comment: wdoes your `Bar` models has `FK` to `Foo` or how do you want to join the instances?

Comment: @Bear Brown yes, I totally forgot that. `Bar` has `FK` to `Foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the save method:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo_rel = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.bar_code and len(self.bar_code.split('-')) > 1:
            # Do update the Bar instance, need remove old previx first
            self.bar_code = self.bar_code.split('-')[1]
        self.bar_code = '{}-{}'.format(self.foo_rel.foo_code, self.bar_code)
        super(Bar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

this will work as follows:

```
>>> f = Foo.objects.create(foo_code='123456')
>>> b = Bar.objects.create(foo_rel=f, bar_code='01')
>>> b.bar_code
u'123456-01'
>>> b.bar_code = '03'
>>> b.save()
>>> b.bar_code
u'123456-03'
>>> f.foo_code = '4567'
>>> f.save()
>>> b.save()
>>> b.bar_code
u'4567-03'
```

and it's looks good, but you should remember it will not work on bulk `update`:

```
>>> Bar.objects.update(bar_code='333')
1
>>> b.refresh_from_db()
>>> b.bar_code
u'333'
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly fine but in one scenario where `bar_code` is generated with `pre_save` is totally random 5 char string. Since, there is no value assigned to `bar_code` while creating new instance it gives me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`. How to get over this scenario?

Comment: Yeah, now it doesn't throw any error but value of `bar_code` is still `None`. EDIT: I removed `pre_save` and added function directly to the `bar_code`. Thank you.